# Is there possibility of sum of ArrayList without looping

Tags: java

Is there possibility of sum of `ArrayList` without looping?

PHP provides `sum(array)` which will give the sum of array.

The PHP code is like

```
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";
```

I wanted to do the same in Java:

```
List tt = new ArrayList();
tt.add(1);
tt.add(2);
tt.add(3);
```

Comment: What if the `ArrayList` doesn not contain something that is "summable"? ArrayList and an array isn't necessarily the same thing. As for summing numbers in an array, that's a very simple for loop over the elements and calculating a cumulative sum.

Comment: The PHP function `array_sum` also does a loop internally, it just hides it from the user.

Comment: It's a reasonable question.  After all, it's nearly as trivial to write a loop to find the largest element in a list, yet java.util.Collections provides a max() method.

Comment: I suggest the answer provided by Ján Яabčan. I don't know why his answer isn't the most upvoted one, since it provides the most clear and objetive method to accomplish your sum.

Answer (score 195):

Once [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) is out (March 2014) you'll be able to [use streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/):

If you have a `List<Integer>`

```
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

If it's an `int[]`

```
int sum = IntStream.of(a).sum();
```

Comment: `map` uses loops implicitly

Comment: You could use recursion to not use a loop. :D (don't do this)

Comment: stream is too much slow, shit...

Answer (score 27):

Then write it yourself:

```
public int sum(List<Integer> list) {
     int sum = 0; 

     for (int i : list)
         sum = sum + i;

     return sum;
}
```

Comment: Or extending ArrayList with the sum method so you have it built in to your own ArrayList.

Comment: When doing the actual addition, it's just nicer to use a simple `int`. There is little value in using `Integer` with java's auto-boxing features here. Also, you are creating and recreating potentially many new `Integer` objects each time, since it is an `Immutable` type.

Answer (score 11):

The only alternative to using a loop is to use recursion.

You can define a method like

```
public static int sum(List<Integer> ints) {
   return ints.isEmpty() ? 0 : ints.get(0) + ints.subList(1, ints.length());
}
```

This is very inefficient compared to using a plain loop and can blow up if you have many elements in the list.

An alternative which avoid a stack overflow is to use.

```
public static int sum(List<Integer> ints) {
    int len = ints.size();
    if (len == 0) return 0;
    if (len == 1) return ints.get(0);
    return sum(ints.subList(0, len/2)) + sum(ints.subList(len/2, len));
}
```

This is just as inefficient, but will avoid a stack overflow.

---

The shortest way to write the same thing is

```
int sum = 0, a[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};

for(int i: a) {
    sum += i;
}

System.out.println("sum(a) = " + sum);
```

prints

```
sum(a) = 20
```

Comment: In the code you miss the call to sum() in the first recursive definition. The second recursive definition does not prevent stack overflow from happening, it makes it less likely.

Comment: @Teudimundo True, While it doesn't prevent it, the maximum size of a List is Integer.MAX_VALUE and the log2 is 31 which is maximum depth. Most systems have many thousands of calls as a limit but if you are very close to the this it could still blow.

Answer (score 9):

Write a util function like

```
public class ListUtil{

    public static int sum(List<Integer> list){
      if(list==null || list.size()<1)
        return 0;

      int sum = 0;
      for(Integer i: list)
        sum = sum+i;

      return sum;
    }
}
```

Then use like

```
int sum = ListUtil.sum(yourArrayList)
```

Comment: but how can i do it for long value in arraylist ?

Answer (score 9):

for me the clearest way is this:

```
doubleList.stream().reduce((a,b)->a+b).get();
```

or

```
doubleList.parallelStream().reduce((a,b)->a+b).get();
```

It also use internal loops, but it is not possible without loops.

Comment: This is the most clear and objetive answer for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache commons-collections API.

```
class AggregateClosure implements org.apache.commons.collections.Closure {
        int total = 0;

        @Override
        public void execute(Object input) {
            if (input != null) {
                total += (Integer) input;
            }
        }

        public int getTotal() {
            return total;
        }
    }
```

Then use this closure as shown below:

```
public int aggregate(List<Integer> aList) {
        AggregateClosure closure = new AggregateClosure();
        org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.forAllDo(aList, closure);
        return closure.getTotal();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with reduce using method references `reduce(Integer::sum)`:

```java
Integer reduceSum = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 6, 4)
        .stream()
        .reduce(Integer::sum)
        .get();
```

Or without `Optional`:

```
Integer reduceSum = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 6, 4)
        .stream()
        .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know about the map function, then you know that a map is also can be recursive loop or recursive loop. But obviously you have to reach each element for that.   so, I could not work out the Java 8, because some syntax mismatch but wanted a very short so this is what I got.

```
int sum = 0
for (Integer e : myList) sum += e;
```

Comment: You are right. I said it's a minimal  loop instead of map which can be tail recursive.

Comment: "Is there possibility of sum of ArrayList without looping"

Answer (score 0):

Given that a list can hold any type of object, there is no built in method which allows you to sum all the elements. You could do something like this:

```
int sum = 0;

for( Integer i : ( ArrayList<Integer> )tt ) {
  sum += i;
}
```

Alternatively you could create your own container type which inherits from ArrayList but also implements a method called sum() which implements the code above.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a **Collection** of elements (in the form of list), primitive are stored as wrapper class object but at the same time i can store objects of String class as well. SUM will not make sense in that. BTW why are so afraid to use for loop (enhanced or through iterator) anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Or switch to Groovy, it has a sum() function on a collection.
[1,2,3,4,5,6].sum()

http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections

Runs on the same JVM as your java classes.

Comment: Yeah. Sum function is definitely reason to switch to another language. :D

Comment: The question is tagged `Java`, so this is technically not a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/sum-values-in-arraylist/) shows three different ways how to sum in java, there is one option that is not in previous answers using Apache Commons Math..

Example:

```
public static void main(String args []){
    List<Double> NUMBERS_FOR_SUM = new ArrayList<Double>(){
         {
            add(5D);
            add(3.2D);
            add(7D);
         }
    };
    double[] arrayToSume = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(NUMBERS_FOR_SUM
            .toArray(new Double[NUMBERS_FOR_SUM.size()]));    
    System.out.println(StatUtils.sum(arrayToSume));

}
```

See [StatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/StatUtils.html) api

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GNU Trove](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove) library:

```
TIntList tt = new TIntArrayList();
tt.add(1);
tt.add(2);
tt.add(3);
int sum = tt.sum();
```