# Need something like getTotal(ClassName, ListOfObjectsOfClass, numericFieldOfClass)

Tags: java, utility, utility-method

I have class say for example `public class Item {
    int price;
    String name;
      // getters and setters
}`
I have such 1000 or more objects (just example).
For each item there is a different price. And All this item objects are in `List<Item>` my requirement is to get total price (i.e price for item 1 to nth item of the list).

Is there any utility or way by which i can get total for the particular field (i.e total price of all the items). I just give List, ClassName and fieldName I get the total? I know we can get the total by iterating through the list, call get method  add all up and store in some variable.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is similar to another one:
[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963847/is-there-possibility-of-sum-of-arraylist-without-looping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just written a simple method which calculates a sum of some properties in list:

> ```
> public static <E> Integer sum(List<E> obejcts, String propertyName) throws 
>         IllegalAccessException, 
>         InvocationTargetException, 
>         NoSuchMethodException {
>     Integer sum = 0;
>     for (Object o: obejcts) {
>         sum += (Integer)PropertyUtils.getProperty(o, propertyName);
>     }
>     return sum;
> }
> ```

For this I use [javabeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) technology. You can download  needed libraries directly from [apache site](http://commons.apache.org/).

Here's example of using it:

> public class MyObject {
>   private int x;
>
> public MyObject() {
>             }
>
> public int getX() {         return x;   }
>
> public void setX(int x) {       this.x = x;     }
>
> }

And calculating sum:

> ```
> List<MyObject> l = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
> ...
> try {
> int a = sum(l,"x");
> System.out.print(a);
> } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK not in the standard JDK, but there are functions for this in many existing libraries. For example with [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) you should be able to do `sumFrom(objects, on(Object.class).getField())`