# Sum of elements of an Integer ArrayList without looping

Tags: java, arraylist

I have gone through a few web resources and links, however, I am unable to find the sum of elements of an Integer ArrayList without looping. I am looking for a function which will allow me to do this in a single line.

I was able to find the same for a normal array as follows

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class sumArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = {10,20,30,40,50};
        int sum = IntStream.of(a).sum();
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

I can write a user-defined function as follows

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sumAL
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        al.add(1);
        al.add(3);
        al.add(5);

        System.out.println(sum(al));
    }

    static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> al)
    {
        int value = 0;
        for(int i : al)
        {
            value += i;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

However, I'm looking for something in-built.
Please advise.

EDIT : I have tried the following but I get build errors

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sumAL
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getVersion());

        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        al.add(1);
        al.add(3);
        al.add(5);
        System.out.println(al.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
    }

    static double getVersion () {
        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        int pos = version.indexOf('.');
        pos = version.indexOf('.', pos+1);
        return Double.parseDouble (version.substring (0, pos));
    }
}
```

Errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Integer cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

Comment: one way or another some looping will be used, you can use a divide-and-conquer recursive (or iterative) approach since sums satisfy the partial sums property, i.e a **sum is equal to the sum of partial sums**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there possibility of sum of ArrayList without looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963847/is-there-possibility-of-sum-of-arraylist-without-looping)

Comment: @saltandwater What errors do you get?

Comment: @kajacx, please see edit above for errors

Comment: Are you sure you are using java 8? Run `java -version` from command line or check java instalation folder for version. Streams (you are using those) are only avaliable in java 8.

Comment: java -version gives me 1.8. I also tested using getVersion() code above and it gives me 1.8

Answer (score 1):

You can easily map a `Stream<Integer>` to an `IntStream` and then calculate the sum :

```
a1.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Comment: `map` uses loops implicitly!

Comment: @NikosM. I don't think the OP minds that. He's just looking for a built-in method.

Comment: @NikosM. You'll always have some loop behind the scenes, since you must iterate over all the elements in order to calculate the sum.

Comment: @Eran, thanks for the response. I have tried the above, but I get some build errors, please see EDIT above. Is it something related to java versioning?

Comment: @saltandwater You must have java 8.

Comment: @Takendarkk, I do have java version 1.8. Please see edit above.

Comment: @Eran, sorry didn't get you. I said, I do have java version 1.8

Comment: @saltandwater sorry about that, not enough sleep

Comment: @Eran, :) guessed it. Are you able to compile my code from the edit above?

Comment: @saltandwater I tested the code on ideone.com and it worked - http://ideone.com/e.js/76vf9v

Answer (score 1):

```
al.stream().reduce(0, (x,y) -> x+y)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.