# Best way to sum an integer list

Tags: java

I was wondering what the *best* way to sum the elements of an integer list in java is.

I'm aware I could perform this with a for loop but I was expecting there might be inbuilt ways to do this, such as the reduce function in other languages.

The relevant code for this problem has been provided below.

```
  public static int sumList(List<Integer> list) {
    return 0; //should return sum of integers in list
  }
```

Comment: do you know the stream api?

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963847/is-there-possibility-of-sum-of-arraylist-without-looping) show how you can do that with streams.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Stream API in Java 8

```
return list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

The `.mapToInt(i -> i)` is required as Java doesn't know how to sum any object but it does know how to sum an `IntStream` and this converts the `Stream<Integer>` into an `IntStream`

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for